# dnsmasq failed to start on Debian

Tags: linux, debian

This is the content of systemctl status dnsmasq.service:

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-06-29 12:37:37 CEST; 23s ago
  Process: 24641 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 24638 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

This is the journal content:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-06-25 11:49:21 CEST, end at Sat 2019-06-29 12:48:50 CEST. --
Jun 25 11:49:29 EddLinux kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: preinit failed with -22
Jun 25 11:49:29 EddLinux kernel: nouveau: DRM:00000000:00000080: init failed with -22
Jun 25 11:49:32 EddLinux avahi-daemon[297]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
Jun 25 11:49:33 EddLinux systemd-rfkill[421]: Failed to open device: No such device
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: Failed to get interface index: No such device
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: 
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: 
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux dhclient[502]: exiting.
Jun 25 11:49:35 EddLinux systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jun 25 11:49:44 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 12:17:49 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 13:32:38 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 13:32:43 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 17:36:10 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 18:29:26 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 25 18:46:36 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 25 18:50:57 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 26 12:29:22 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 13:08:52 EddLinux anacron[4522]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
Jun 26 14:20:05 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 14:31:18 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 26 15:38:34 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 15:38:47 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jun 26 15:38:47 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 26 15:42:56 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 26 15:52:46 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 16:21:11 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 26 17:39:35 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 18:16:05 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 26 18:25:44 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 26 20:30:11 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 27 16:39:10 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 27 17:06:50 EddLinux anacron[11980]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
Jun 27 17:38:13 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 27 18:11:44 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 27 18:12:28 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 27 18:50:12 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 28 11:46:18 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 28 11:48:33 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jun 28 11:48:33 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 28 11:48:55 EddLinux kernel: FAT-fs (sdb1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
Jun 28 11:53:31 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jun 28 11:53:31 EddLinux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 28 11:53:41 EddLinux wpa_supplicant[571]: nl80211: Unexpected encryption algorithm 5
Jun 28 12:08:31 EddLinux anacron[17533]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
Jun 28 12:52:24 EddLinux kernel: ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20160831/evevent-291)
Jun 29 12:13:35 EddLinux anacron[21404]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
Jun 29 12:35:05 EddLinux dnsmasq[24574]: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
Jun 29 12:35:05 EddLinux dnsmasq[24574]: FAILED to start up
Jun 29 12:35:05 EddLinux systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jun 29 12:37:37 EddLinux dnsmasq[24641]: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
Jun 29 12:37:37 EddLinux dnsmasq[24641]: FAILED to start up
Jun 29 12:37:37 EddLinux systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

I've already reinstalled it.
Any help will be welcomed!

Comment: It’s probably systemd-resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

> failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use

That's it.

DNS uses queries which send data on port 53 (most of the time UDP, but TCP can also be used).

`dnsmasq` is (among other things) a so-called forwarding DNS *server,* and the fact it's a server means it wants to *listen* on at least 53/UDP and also maybe on 53/TCP.

Only a single process (running program) is able to listen on a port with a particular number on a particular IP address.
So the error means that some other program already listens on port 53, and `dnsmasq` fails to do that, and exits.

### What to do about it

First, figure out what's listening on 53/UDP.

1. Install `iproute2`:

   ```
   # apt install iproute2
   ```
2. See who's using 53/UDP:

   ```
   # ss -nlup
   ```

   The options mean:

   - Show **n**umeric addresses, do not attempt to DNS-resolve them.
   - Show only **l**istening sockets.
   - Show only **u**dp sockets (actually, endpoints but never mind).
   - Show **p**rocesses which opened those sockets.

   (Note that you have to run this program as `root`—maybe via `sudo`; this depends on how you configured the way to elevate privileges on your system.)

   Now locate a record in the output containing something like
   `[::]:53` — the exact reading may differ, say, `0.0.0.0:53`, but you'll see that `:53` suffix for sure—that's the port number,—and then see the "users" column—it should list the name of the program which opened that socket.

   Say, on my system the relevant like looks like `UNCONN 0 0                    [::]:53 [::]:* users:(("dnsmasq",pid=601,fd=6))` (I have condensed whitespace a bit for brevity). Notice the user is `dnsmasq`; on your system this will be different.

OK, so once you figured out who's the culprit, try thinking through how to uninstall that program. After doing that, simple `# systemctl restart dnsmasq` shall have your going.